# SQL Double counting

Tags: sql

So I am working with data that has a premise ID and a subscriber ID.

Each premise ID represents a house and subscriber ID represents individuals who have purchased from that house.

Therefore, we can have Premise ID = 1 with 3 Subscriber ID's attached to it.

I am new to SQL and am really struggling with getting my mind around premise level vs subscriber level, especially when joining.

I don't actually have a specific question, but was wondering if anyone could give me tips on how to think about this when approaching problems in trying to extract specific bits of data.

Comment: Can't really do anything without anything.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. There are many SQL tutorials and books available out there. This site is for specific questions, and if you don't actually have one then unfortunately you cannot post here. The [tour] and [help] pages have more information regarding how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

Each Premise = Man. Each Subscriber = Child.
So, 1 man can have multiple child, but each child can only have 1 father.

How are they related? Each child have a father (premiseId).

So multiple child could have the same father (man), but each child can only have 1 father. And each father (man) can have multiple child.

So, let's say you are in a big playground with hundreds of man, and thousands of children. You want to know which child (subscriber) is related to a particular man (premise).

So, you search through the playground and ask: Which children have a particular man Id:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE premise_id = 1
```

Or you can link them together:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriber INNER JOIN premise ON premise.id = subscriber.premise_id
```

You can get the same effect with:

```
SELECT * FROM premise LEFT JOIN subscriber ON subscriber.premise_id = premise.id
```

Does this make more sense?